# Зачем хостер блокирует исходящий 25 SMTP порт?

Tags: email, smtp, vps, hosting

В моём случае три исходящих порта заблокированы: 25, 465, 587. Как это может предотвратить спам-рассылки, если почту можно отправлять с любого порта?

Comment: Для этого кто-то должен поднять SMTP-сервер на «любом» порту.

Comment: Кажется понял, т.е. предполагается что взломщик не имеет доступа к настройке SMTP-сервера.

Comment: Разумеется обычно взломщик не имеет доступа к настройке SMTP-сервера яндекса, гугла и т.п., а поднятием своего SMTP-сервера они не заморачиваются.